# Attempting to Connect to Remote Server with C# Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, client-server

What I am trying to do is connect to a remote server and read a text file and then display it in the console. The remote server requires a username and password for access. I would like to ask you guys what the best way to do this is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace WebclientTest
{


class Server
{
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    private string hostName;
    private string userName;
    private string password;

    //Constructor gets host username and password
    public Server(string _hostName, string _userName, string _password)
    {
        hostName = _hostName;
        userName = _userName;
        password = _password;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        AllocConsole();
        //Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld");
        //Console.ReadLine();
        Uri uri = new Uri(hostName);
        Console.WriteLine(uri.Host.ToString());
        string fileLocation = uri.Host+"\someDirectory.textfile.txt";
        StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
        Console.Write(strRead.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what authentication type? basic-auth? forms?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way, but I've done something similar by mapping a drive and then using the mapped drive letter to access the file:

```
    private void mapDrive(String strDrive, String strLocation, string strUser, string strPassword)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc  = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "use " + @strDrive + " " + @strLocation + " " + @" /USER:" + @strUser + " " + @strPassword;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

When you're done, make sure to remove the mapping:

```
    private void unmapDrive(String strDrive)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "use " + @strDrive + @" /delete /yes";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```